# Linq safety checks

Tags: vb.net, linq

I was working on the following code:

```
Dim xyzTotal As Decimal?
Dim ins = Recins

If ins IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each obj In ins
        If obj.DCovers isNot Nothing Then
            For Each cover In obj.DCovers
                If cover.Event.Code.ToUpper().Contains("XYZ") Then
                    xyzTotal += cover.Value
                End If
            Next
        End If  
    Next
End If
Return xyzTotal
```

Wrote the following LINQ statement for this:

```
Dim xyzTotal As Decimal?
Dim ins = Recins

If ins IsNot Nothing Then
    For Each obj In ins
        obj.DCovers.Where(Function(x) x.Event.Code.ToUpper().Contains("TPD")).ToList().ForEach(Function(y) xyzTotal = xyzTotal + y.Value)
    Next

End If
Return xyzTotal
```

How can I put the checks (like I did in the above code) to my LINQ statement to make sure that it should produce an error when any of the values do not exist. A single line LINQ (instead of Foreach above) will be much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB 14 you can use null-conditional operator (`?.`) :

```
Dim xyzTotal As Decimal? = ins?.DCovers? _
                               .Where(Function(x) x.Event.Code.ToUpper().Contains("TPD")) _
                               .Sum(Function(x) x.Value)
```

[Visual Basic .NET - 14 Top Improvements in Visual Basic 14](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890368.aspx)

Comment: Hi @har07
I'm using .net fw 4.5, do I have any option to do it in that?

Comment: @sam Language features come with the version of Visual Studio, not the .NET framework. You have to be using VS 2015, then you can target any .NET version it supports.

Comment: @GSerg You mean I can use `?.` in .net 4.5 project as long as I'm using VS2015? (don't have VS2015 atm to test)

Comment: @har07 Yes I mean that.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Where` function to filter out any `obj` elements that have a null `DCovers` property.

You can also use the `Aggregate` function to create the sum of the elements.

```
Dim xyzTotal As Decimal?
Dim ins = Recins

If ins IsNot Nothing Then
    xyzTotal = ins _
        .Where(Function(x) x.DCovers IsNot Nothing) _
        .SelectMany(Function(x) x.DCovers) _
        .Where(Function(x) x.Event.Code.ToUpper().Contains("XYZ")) _
        .Aggregate(New Decimal?, Function(total, current) If(total, 0D) + current.Value)
End If

Return xyzTotal
```

Note that when you use the `Aggregate` function you will need to start with a null value (`New Decimal?`), and then coalesce that to zero when performing the sum, because a null value plus a non-null value results in a null value.

As @har07 says, you could also use the null-conditional operator on the `ins` variable if you are using Visual Studio 2015:

```
xyzTotal = ins?.Where(Function(x) x.DCovers IsNot Nothing)...
```